# convert columns to rows in pandas based on condition

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to convert columns into multiple rows using pandas.I have the data in following table in a database. Attached below is the csv format

```
CustomerID,Expiry_Date,ProductA,ProductAType,ProductB,ProductBType,ProductC,ProductCType,ProductD,ProductDType,ProductF,ProductFType,ProductG,ProductGType
1,22/11/2020,YES,Trial,NO,Nan,NO,Nan,NO,Nan,YES,Full,NO,Nan
2,30/12/2020,NO,Nan,YES,Full,NO,Nan,NO,Nan,NO,Nan,NO,Nan
3,01/12/2020,NO,Nan,NO,Nan,YES,Full,YES,Trial,NO,Nan,NO,Nan
```

Here is the sample data as a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = StringIO("""CustomerID,Expiry_Date,ProductA,ProductAType,ProductB,ProductBType,ProductC,ProductCType,ProductD,ProductDType,ProductF,ProductFType,ProductG,ProductGType
1,22/11/2020,YES,Trial,NO,Nan,NO,Nan,NO,Nan,YES,Full,NO,Nan
2,30/12/2020,NO,Nan,YES,Full,NO,Nan,NO,Nan,NO,Nan,NO,Nan
3,01/12/2020,NO,Nan,NO,Nan,YES,Full,YES,Trial,NO,Nan,NO,Nan""")
df=pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

The table contains a list of around 50 columns and YES and NO option is the Customer has bought the product.

I need to transpose the rows to columns and output a customer, expiry_id and a product_column with Product_name if the customer has it and its type. as follows.

```
CustomerID,Expiry_Date,Product,Type
1,22/11/2020,ProductA,Trial
1,22/11/2020,ProductF,Full
2,30/12/2020,ProductB,Full
3,01/12/2020,ProductC,Full
3,01/12/2020,ProductD,Trial
```

The last two columns can be one concatenated column as well like

```
CustomerID,Expiry_Date,Product
1,22/11/2020,ProductA-Trial
1,22/11/2020,ProductF-Full
2,30/12/2020,ProductB-Full
3,01/12/2020,ProductC-Full
3,01/12/2020,ProductD-Trial
```

Any idea how this can be achieved in pandas or sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with filter `YES` values with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and drop column in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.melt(['CustomerID','Expiry_Date'], var_name='Product')
df = df[df.pop('value').eq('YES')]
```

EDIT: Convert first columns to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) pairs and unpairs columns, then filter in both `Series` by `Yes` values:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['CustomerID','Expiry_Date'])

s1 = df1.iloc[:, ::2].stack(dropna=False)
mask = s1.eq('YES').to_numpy()
s1 = s1[mask]
s2 = df1.iloc[:, 1::2].stack(dropna=False)
s2 = s2[mask]
```

---

```
print (s1)
CustomerID  Expiry_Date          
1           22/11/2020   ProductA    YES
                         ProductF    YES
2           30/12/2020   ProductB    YES
3           01/12/2020   ProductC    YES
                         ProductD    YES
dtype: object

print (s2)
CustomerID  Expiry_Date              
1           22/11/2020   ProductAType    Trial
                         ProductFType     Full
2           30/12/2020   ProductBType     Full
3           01/12/2020   ProductCType     Full
                         ProductDType    Trial
dtype: object
```

Last convert 3rd level to column and rename, for second remove third level and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = s1.reset_index(level=2).rename(columns={'level_2':'Product'})['Product']
df2 = s2.reset_index(level=2, drop=True).rename('Type')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
dtype: object
   CustomerID Expiry_Date   Product   Type
0           1  22/11/2020  ProductA  Trial
1           1  22/11/2020  ProductF   Full
2           2  30/12/2020  ProductB   Full
3           3  01/12/2020  ProductC   Full
4           3  01/12/2020  ProductD  Trial
```

Last if need join use `+=` with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for remove column:

```
df['Product'] += '-' + df.pop('Type') 
print (df)
   CustomerID Expiry_Date         Product
0           1  22/11/2020  ProductA-Trial
1           1  22/11/2020   ProductF-Full
2           2  30/12/2020   ProductB-Full
3           3  01/12/2020   ProductC-Full
4           3  01/12/2020  ProductD-Trial
```

Comment: How would we handle an output where each product has a product type column next to it.
for example each product has a type column next to it which will be Full or trial if the value is yes.

And if value is yes in the Product Column I want full or Trial for any product that is yes

Comment: @Junaid388 - Can you change data how it looks? Please no picture, it was reason for both downvotes.

Comment: How can I share the data then? html table?

Comment: @Junaid388 - It is super, text is best here

Comment: @Junaid388 - It is now more complicated, asnwer was edited.